# How to get the following geometric summation?

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to show that, for $t > 0$,
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}
\exp\left(-4\left[-2 + {4{\rm i} \over n}\right]t\right)
=
\sinh\left(8t\right)
\left[1 + \coth\left(\frac{8t}{n}\right) \right].
$$

Comment: Hint: it is just a geometric sum, $\sum_{i=1}^nr^i =r\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ for some $r$

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Could be wrong.

Comment: @GiulioR Oh. I see.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank. Can you please tell me the reason? So there is a typo？

Comment: $$
{1 \over n}\,{{\rm e}^{8t} \over {\rm e}^{16t/n}\,\,\,\, -\,\, 1}
\stackrel{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\quad {{\rm e}^{8t} \over 16t}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series in question is
\begin{align}
S_{n}^{1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{8 t - (16 t/n) \, k} = e^{8 t} \, \frac{1 - e^{- 16 t}}{1 - e^{-16 t/n}} \\
&= e^{8 t/n} \, \frac{\sinh(8 t)}{\sinh\left(\frac{8 t}{n}\right)} \tag{1} \\
&= \sinh(8 t) \, \left( 1 + \frac{1 + e^{- 16 t/n}}{1 - e^{-16 t/n}} \right) \\
&= \sinh(8 t) \, \left(1 + \coth\left(\frac{8 t}{n}\right) \right). \tag{2}
\end{align}

A related series is:
\begin{align}
S_{n}^{2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{8 t - 16 t \, k/n} &= e^{8 t} \, \frac{1 - e^{- 16 (n+1) t/n}}{1 - e^{-16 t/n}} \\
&= \frac{\sinh(8 t + 8 t/n)}{\sinh(8 t/n)} \\
&= \sinh(8 t) \, \left( \tanh\left(\frac{8 t}{n}\right) + \coth\left(\frac{8 t}{n}\right) \right). \tag{3}
\end{align}

Both series have the same limiting form
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n}^{1, 2} = 2 \, \sinh(8 t). $$

Comment: @Hermi   If $n \to \infty$ the the last series has the value $ 2 \, \sinh(8 t)$.

Comment: @Hermi   The $k \in \{0, n-1\}$ series has been added.