# Can we solve that the following inequality on $t$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

For a fix $\epsilon>0$, I want to solve the following inequality about $t>0$ where $n$ is some large positive integer
$$
\frac{e^{4t}}{\sqrt{\sinh\left(8t\right)
\left[1 + \coth\left(\frac{8t}{n}\right) \right]}}\ge \epsilon
$$

Can we get $t\gtrsim n^\alpha$ from the above inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as showing that, which follows from the results of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4581307/148155),
$$ \sqrt{\frac{1 - e^{- 16 \, t/n}}{1 - e^{-16 \, t}}} \geq \epsilon $$
for large $n$.
This leads to, by expanding the exponentials,
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \, \sqrt{1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \, (8 \, t) + \mathcal{O}(t^2)} \geq \epsilon $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \, \left( 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \, (4 \, t) + \mathcal{O}(t^2) \right) \geq \epsilon. $$

The desired result should follow from this result.

Comment: Thanks! But how to deal with $O(t^2)$ if I want to lower bound $t$?

Comment: It seems that this gives us $t\le \frac{1-\sqrt{n}\epsilon +O(t^2)}{1-(1/n)}$.

Comment: @Hermi minimum value would suggest that $ t \geq -\sqrt{n}/4 $.

Comment: Ok, can we get better lower bound like $t\ge n^{\alpha}$ without the minus sign...